# Decrypting URL not working

Tags: java, web-services, encryption, cryptography

The problem I am facing is that I could not get decrypted email when I call this REST service: http://localhost:8080/RestWebService/MM/decryptEmail

For more details I also add an image below.
I hope I have explained my question well

```
package client;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import my.web.services.KeysGeneration;

public class TestClient {
    private static String keypass = "KHU12345KHU12345";
    public static void callPostService()
    {
        try{
            URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/RestWebService/MM");
            HttpURLConnection conn =(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            // Allow Inputs
            conn.setDoInput(true);

            // Allow Outputs
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            // Don't use a cached copy.
            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            String text;
            OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
            String email="sabah@gmail.com";

//          //**********AES Encryption


//           // Create key and cipher
            SecretKey aesKey = KeysGeneration.getKeys(keypass);

                Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
//              // encrypt the text
                cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, aesKey);
                byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(email.getBytes());
                System.out.println("checking encryption "+new String(encrypted));
               writer.write("&email="+(encrypted));

//               //**********AES Encryption 

////                //**********AES Decryption
//
////                // decrypt the text
                cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, aesKey);
                String decrypted= new String(cipher.doFinal(encrypted));
                System.out.println("checking dencryption "+decrypted);
////
//////                   //**********AES Decryption

            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();
            byte[] b = new byte[1024];
            int len = 0;
            while((len=stream.read(b, 0,1024))>0)
            {
                System.out.println(new String(b,0,len));
            }
            stream.close();

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void callGETService()
    {
        try{
            URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/RestWebService/MM?email=sabah@khu.ac.kr&pwd=1985");
            HttpURLConnection conn =(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            // Allow Inputs
            conn.setDoInput(true);

            // Allow Outputs
            conn.setDoOutput(false);

            // Don't use a cached copy.
            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();
            byte[] b = new byte[1024];
            int len = 0;
            while((len=stream.read(b, 0,1024))>0)
            {
                System.out.println(new String(b,0,len));
            }

            stream.close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // open your connection
        TestClient.callGETService();
        TestClient.callPostService();
    }

}

//webService

package my.web.services;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.ws.rs.FormParam;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;

@Path("/MM")
public class WebService {

    private String keypass = "KHU12345KHU12345";

    //********GET Method*************

    @GET
    //GET method provides read only access to resources
    public String validateUserGETMethod(@QueryParam("email")String email, @QueryParam("pwd")String pwd)

    {
        return "Using GET method \n Email address: "+email+ " and password:" +pwd;
    }


    //********POST Method*************

    //POST method is used to create or update a new resources
    //To generate encryption of email parameter

    @POST
    @Path("/encryptEmail")
    public String validateUserPOSTMethodEncryption(@FormParam("email")String email)throws Exception

    {
        // Create key and cipher
        SecretKey aesKey = KeysGeneration.getKeys(keypass);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        // encrypt the text
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, aesKey);
        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(email.getBytes());
        System.err.println(new String(encrypted));

        return "Using POST method \n Email address (encrypted): "+new String(encrypted);

    }


    //POST method is used to create or update a new resources
    //To  generate decryption of email parameter
    @POST
    @Path("/decryptEmail")
    public String validateUserPOSTMethodDecryption(@FormParam("email")String email)throws Exception

    {
        //SecretKey aesKey = KeysGeneration.getKeys(keypass);
        SecretKey secKey = KeysGeneration.getKeys(keypass);//generator.generateKey();

        // Create key and cipher
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");


        // decrypt the text
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secKey);
        String decrypted= new String(cipher.doFinal(email.getBytes()));

        return "Using POST method \n Email address (decrypted): "+decrypted;
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: You have not explained the question well at all.

Comment: I have send encrypted email from TestClient and I want to decrypt it by using webService code. But when i type in REST(as shown in image) i get error 500.

Comment: If you get an HTTP 500 error on the client side, an error has occurred on the server side. Please check the server's log and add the full error (incl. stacktrace) to the question.

Comment: The output of a cipher is binary data. Binary data cannot be directly converted into a String (with any character set). You have to use a hexadecimal or a Base64 encoding. Your server side expects the parameters as form data. In a POST request, you have to URL encode it. Even Base64 is needs to be URL encoded first as it contains characters not valid in an URL. At then there's the encryption problems: no IV, padding not specified, default and inappropriate chaining mode...

Answer (score 0):

hi thank you i solved problem by your kind suggestion.  I want to show you if I am calculating time correctly required for encryption: Here is my code

```
//          //**********AES Encryption
            //checking time in msec
            long startTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
            //System.out.println(startTime);
            //           // Create key and cipher
            SecretKey aesKey = KeysGeneration.getKeys(keypass);

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
            //              // encrypt the text
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, aesKey);
            byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(email.getBytes());
            System.out.println("checking encryption "+new String(encrypted));

            BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
            email = encoder.encode(encrypted);
            System.out.println("Encoded Encrypted Value="+email);

            // text="&email="+URLEncoder.encode(new String(encrypted), "UTF-8");
            writer.write("&email="+email);
            //Calculating Encryption Time
            long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Duration ms=Duration.ofMillis(stopTime);

            //System.out.println(stopTime);
            long elapsedTime = stopTime - startTime;
            System.out.println("Time required for encryption (milliseconds)= "+elapsedTime);
```